# Episode extraction

Tags: r, dataframe

I totally lost on this. I am using time-use data I would like to extract episodes based on time steps. So basically, individuals are asked to take 3 measurements at the same time denoted by 3 variables a_1, b_1 and c_1. In some cases, they reported the same measurement at a_2, b_2 and c_2. I would like to extract the length (the minimum length is 2) of the same measurements based on time-steps the frequency of the occurrence as well the start and end times.

For example, below the highlighted red and blue cells denote same measurement based on time-steps and *not per id.*

[image]

[image]

Possible output:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
Sample data:

structure(list(a_1 = c(100, 100, NA), a_2 = c(101, 101, NA), 
    a_3 = c(100, 100, NA), a_4 = c(1234, 1234, NA), b_1 = c(4567, 
    100, NA), b_2 = c(101, 101, NA), b_3 = c(100, 100, NA), b_4 = c(1234, 
    1234, NA), c_1 = c(3456, 100, NA), c_2 = c(101, 101, NA), 
    c_3 = c(100, 100, NA), c_4 = c(1234, 1234, NA)), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(a_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a_4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), b_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), b_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), b_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), b_4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), c_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), c_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), c_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), c_4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Help me understand the problem better. If you are talking about "same measurement" do you mean that for example a_1 is the same as a_3, that a_1 is the same as b_1 or that a_1 is the same as a later a_1? Also how are the interval and measurement columns decided exactly?

Comment: @WietsedeVries thanks so the 'same measurement' is based on timestep. So basically you report a 3 times a measurement for a timestep at a1,b1,c1; the number 1 denotes the time-step; a2,b2,c2 means a,b,c measurement at timestep 2 and so on. I am interested to find out if during timestep 1 a,b,c measurements are identical or not and to move to time step 2

Comment: So the length is based on the amount of measurements that are identical (i.e. _2, _3, _4) and occurrence is the amount of rows? I see that _1 is identical in the second row, why is this not in your expected output?

Comment: @WietsedeVries thanks that si a mistake. I will update this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, -id) %>%
  separate(key, into = c("Msrm", "TS"), sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(id, TS) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(value)==1 & !is.na(value)) %>%
  select(-Msrm) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  pivot_wider(id, TS) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(sort(current_vars()), -id) %>%
  mutate(Length = rowSums(!is.na(.)),
         Interval = apply(., 1, function(x) paste(which(!is.na(x)), collapse = ", "))) %>%
  unite("Measurement", 1:4, sep = ",", na.rm = T) %>%
  group_by(across(everything())) %>%
  summarize(Occurance = n())
```

which results to:

```
  Measurement      Length Interval   Occurance
  <chr>             <dbl> <chr>          <int>
1 101,100,1234          3 1, 2, 3            1
2 101,100,1234,100      4 1, 2, 3, 4         1
```

Edit:
First things first we will need an id. Since we are going to mutate our data a lot you will lose sight of your ordering.

Next, we `gather`. This is the same as `pivot_longer` and `melt` (from `reshape2` or `data.table`). It creates a tidy table with only 1 column of values and all of the old column names together in a new id column.

Now that we have the columnnames in a column we can easily manipulate them, so we `separate` them into Msrm (a, b, c) and TS (1, 2, 3, 4).

Since we want to see if for each id if all measurements are the same across a single TS we will `group by` id and TS. With these groups we can filter for `n_distinct==1` to only keep timesteps where all values are the exact same, ignoring NA.

At this point there is no need anymore for the Msrm column so we remove it and also we remove the duplicates with the `distinct` function. Lastly we re-arrange the table by id.

Next we do `pivot_wider` to create a value column for each unique TS (1, 2, 3, 4), a bit like our original table. We also remove the id column since there is no use for it anymore at this point and sort the TS to make sure they are in the right order (1, 2, 3, 4).

At this point the table looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
    `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA   101   100  1234
2   100   101   100  1234
```

From here on we calculate the results. First we do the `rowSum` of a boolean (`!is.na()`), this essentially counts the number of columns in a row that are not equal to NA.

Then we use an `apply` to find the column names (`which`) attached to these `!is.na()` values. We wrap it in `paste(..., collapse = ", ")` to print all the column names into a single cell.

After that we can use `unite` to concatenate all the value columns into one while simultaneously removing the original columns. Right now it assumed that you have 4 timesteps (1:4), you could pretty easily make it dynamic if you so desire.

Lastly we group by all columns and use `n()` to see if any row is identical to another and count the occurrences in case they are.

Comment: Many thanks when you have time could you please explain the code and  what steps you followed

Comment: Edited. Also added a `sort(current_vars())` in the `select` because I noticed the order of the columns could get messy under certain conditions

Comment: Superb, many thanks